# Create JSON tree based on child API call in JavaScript or AngularJS

Tags: javascript

I would be known only parent label. Based on the parent label I will call a child if the child exists for that label. I want to push that child to that parent.

For example, parent

```
[
      {
        "label": "1",
        "id": "role1",
        "children": []
      }
]
```

Finally, I want this kind of JSON:

```
[
      {
        "label": "1",
        "id": "role1",
        "children": [
          {
            "label": "2",
            "id": "role11",
            "children": [
              {
                "label": "3",
                "id": "role111",
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "label": "4",
            "id": "role12",
            "children": [
              {
                "label": "5",
                "id": "role121",
                "children": [
                    "label": "5",
                    "id": "role1211",
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "label": "6",
            "id": "role12",
            "children": [
              {
                "label": "7",
                "id": "role121",
                "children": []
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Javascript or AngulerJS? JS in AngularJS stands for Javascript. Also can you make the question a little more understandable?

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't  a free code writing service. Please show what you have tried and explain problems you have achiving objective in more detail. See: [ask]

Comment: i will be knowing parent label (1) i will call one node API to check child from angular. for 1 if there are children i want to push to parent's children. i want to recursively call API till no child get. refer will code jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eu81273/8LWUc/

Comment: What do you mean by "I would be known only parent label."? Can you elaborate (by editing your question, not answering in comments)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear and you haven't posted any code either. Still from what I see I would suggest you do some check like

```
//loop through the parent array.
function loop(parent){
  parent.map( (value,index) => {
    if (value.child.length == 0){
     // push the json object received from api here
      loop(value.child) // call the function with child item as parent
    }
  })
}
```

Edit: You can modify the below code to make it work as per your requirement.

```
    var arr = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: "a",
    data: []
  }
]
var count = 0;
var newArr = function loop(array){

  count++;
  return array.map ((item,index) => {

    if(item.data.length === 0 && count < 5){
       item.data.push(
         {
          id: count,
          name: "b",
          data: []
         } 
       )
      console.log(item.data);
       newArr(item.data)
      }

  })
}
newArr(arr);

function log(){
  console.log(arr)
}

log();
```